# How do I make Mathematica copy a cell after I re-evaluate it?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

When I edit a cell in the notebook and re-evaluate it, it "overwrites" the input and the output of the previous edit. I want it to copy my edited version to the bottom or something and give me a separate output, not overwriting the old results or old input.

Comment: Just copy the edited Input cell in the Input/Output cell group!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how your input would get overwritten -- can you add a screen grab showing this?

As for the output there is a default option for cells called `CellAutoOverwrite` and also an option for notebooks called `OutputAutoOverwrite` which is `True` by default. If you want to switch off overwriting in all your notebooks you could create a stylesheet to use but I'm sensing you are a new user so the easiest path would be to go to **Format >> Option Inspector...**

To switch off in your notebook choose **Selected Notebook** from the popup menu and set `OutputAutoOverwrite` to False (uncheck the box).

[image]

To switch off globally choose **Global Preferences** from the popup menu.

With this option set to `False` you will get a new `Output` cell for each evaluation:

[image]

Once you know what option controls whatever you want to change you can also set the option programmatically:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], OutputAutoOverwrite -> False]
```

The catch of course is identifying the appropriate option in the first place and to a degree this just comes with experience.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Mike's method seems a fine answer to me, but if you just *occasionally* want to keep an existing output, for instance as a reference to see whether a new evaluation causes a change or not, I usually place the insert beam between input and output cells and press enter, creating an empty cell in-between. This prevents the original output cell from being overwritten.

In addition, I find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (Copy Input from Above) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (Copy Output from Above) often useful in this context. Both commands can also be found in the Insert menu.